# $\overline Y=\varprojlim \pi_i(Y)$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Everything is in the title !

Ribes & Zaleski propose  (cor 1.1.8 of"Profinite Groups") as an exercise to prove $\overline Y=\varprojlim \pi_i(Y)$ where $Y\subset\varprojlim E_i$ is a subset of a projective limit of compact-Hausdorff sets $E_i$ and $\pi_i$ are the projections.

I just know $Y\subset\varprojlim \pi_i(Y)\subset\overline Y$ and that $Y$ is dense in $\varprojlim \pi_i(Y)$.

The authors sugjest to prove that $\varprojlim \pi_i(Y)$ is closed but I don't see how.

If I take a point $x=(x_i)\notin\varprojlim \pi_i(Y)$ i can just say that it exists a $i\in I$ such that $x_i\notin\pi_i(Y)$ and so for $i\leq j$, $x_j\notin\pi_j(Y)$ an so what ?

Have someone an idea ?

Comment: Are you sure this question is actually understandable without having to read the book to find out, e.g., what $Y$ is supposed to be?

Comment: What is $\bar Y$? The notation suggests the closure, but in what space? Also, you should spell out all the assumptions so that the reader does not have to read a book to figure out what is missing.

Comment: Then the inverse limit of $Y_i$'s need not be closed, just take a constant inverse system (identity bonding maps) and $Y_i$'s which are not closed.